# ¿Cómo puedo instalar 7z en la imagen de docker de microsoft?

Tags: c#, docker, heroku

He intentado con este código pero me dice que no se encuentra una referencia al paquete

```
RUN apt -qq update --fix-missing && apt -qq install -y 
p7zip-full \
```

la imágen que estoy usando es mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0

Comment: Probaste simplemente `p7zip` sin lo de `-full`?

Comment: Y esa barra al final de la línea por qué?